# "Pull-Down Resistor" in AC circuit

Tags: ac, pulldown

## Background

I have an Fridland AC doorbell that I am about to make "smart". My approach is to connect a device named a `shelly uni` inside the doorbell that draws power from the doorbells own transformer. The shelly device has inputs to read the button press and I can then decide if I want to sound the doorbell (activating an output) besides being able to get notifications on my phone when someone is at the door. The doorbell transformer outputs 12V AC.

## The problem

I have connected the Shelly to the transformer and power is good. The issue here is the input from the doorbell as the cables pick up noise. I am getting everything between 0V and 17.5V on the input making it impossible to tell when the button has been pressed. If this was a DC circuit it could easily be solved with a PullDown resistor and I'm wondering if this can be done here too? The frequency of the transformer should be the same as on the mains which I think is 50Hz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLAsSj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Place the pull-down between the input and the Sensor_GND pin.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was hoping for but not sure if it was the same approach for an AC circuit. I'm thinking a resistance around 10k would be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

Put a resistor around 10k+ between the input and power ground pins of the shelly. You can also add a diode like a 1N4148 to the input. [image]

Comment: Thanks for you comment and time to draw the diagram. May I ask what the advantage of the diod would be? The Shelly's inputs are rated to work with both AC and DC as long as it's powered by the same.